# Internship in an EU country with a French Visa (non-EU citizen)

Tags: visa

I'm currently studying in France with a French student Visa, which also autorises me to do internships in France.

However, I have an opportunity to do one of my internships in another country of the European Union (Sweden/Germany). I would like to know whether I should apply for a new Visa for the new country, or whether I'm able to do an internship with my French visa in another EU country. I do not hold an European passport. (I am a Brazilian passport holder).

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44265/am-i-allowed-to-do-a-six-week-internship-in-germany-on-a-normal-schengen-visa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The French visa (or a residence permit) does allow you to *stay* up to 90 days in another Schengen country. Therefore, if your internship is shorter than 90 days, you don't necessarily need to apply for a visa or residence permit in Germany or Sweden. However, if your internship would require you to be in another country for more than 90 days, you definitely need to secure some residence title there.

A French visa or residence permit doesn't automatically allow you to *work* in another country in the EU. Whether an internship count as work and requires a specific authorization depends on local rules and the details of the internship (research at a university, paid internship in the private sector, etc.). In Germany, you would typically require permission from the *Bundesagentur für Arbeit* (federal agency for employment). Technically this authorization is not a visa (and, in fact, you have to secure that before applying for a visa if you do need one). Your employer has to take care of that.

In any case, some paperwork is very likely required and you shouldn't assume your French visa is enough. You need to approach your prospective employer about that. If they are not familiar with the procedures, there is a lot of information (in German) on [the website of the Bundesagentur für Arbeit](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/unternehmen/arbeitskraefte/studienfachbezogene-praktika). I am less familiar with the situation in Sweden but I wouldn't assume it's OK to do an internship there without prior permission either.