# Internship in Germany as a non-EU citizen, do I need the internship visa if I am already living in another EU country with a residence permit?

Tags: working-visas, germany, eu, internship

I am a student from outside the European Union currently starting my Master's in Tallinn, Estonia. I have lived here for 3 years already as I completed my bachelor's, naturally, I have a residence permit and visa, which is valid until 2022.

I want to do an internship in Germany and I am trying to find out how to go there.

I have tried to research this everywhere but every single source about non-EU citizens working/interning in Germany is all about people that are coming from a country outside the EU. There is almost zero information about the procedure of someone who is not an EU citizen but resides in the EU, with a residence permit, visa, and free allowance to travel to all EU members for up to 90 days (internship offer I received is for 90 days). 
I am applying for the ZAV approval to work in Germany, but everywhere I look I supposedly need this special "internship visa", but it seems to me that this visa only matters to those who come directly from countries outside the EU and need this internship visa in order to enter the EU, which is not the case as I am already in the EU, but I cannot confirm this information anywhere to my future employer who is concerned about it and they also cannot find any information either, they want the assurance that nothing will go wrong if I just get the ZAV approval and hop on the next plane.

And yes, I tried contacting the embassy in Tallinn but they have been incredibly unhelpful and contradicting so I wanted to ask anyone who has had this experience or knows about it.

Comment: I have no answer for internships this short. But my friend (non-EU citizen, resident in France) needed a Visa to go to Germany and do an internship. Having a visa for tourism doesn't mean you can settle and work. Probably once you find a job, your company will ask you on your immigration situation and they will guide you on the process. I have my doubts you can obtain a work visa by yourself without having already found an employer.

Comment: Did you find the answer?
I have the same question if I study in Portugal

Comment: I addressed a similar issue in https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20545/internship-in-an-eu-country-with-a-french-visa-non-eu-citizen

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of confusion about this issue and it's difficult to find explicit confirmation but your understanding seems right to me. [This document](https://www.fu-berlin.de/sites/career/_ressourcen/Unternehmen_Ressourcen/Info-AG-Studienfachbezogene-Praktika.pdf) from the *Bundesagentur für Arbeit* touches upon it:

> **Brauchen Praktikantinnen/Praktikanten ein Visum?**
>
> Staatsangehörige der EU-Staaten benötigen zur Einreise in die Bundesrepublik Deutschland kein Visum. Staatsangehörige aus Australien, Israel, Japan, Kanada, der Republik Korea, Neuseeland und den Vereinigten Staaten von Amerika können visumsfrei in das Bundesgebiet einreisen und den erforderlichen Aufenthaltstitel für das Praktikum bei der örtlichen Ausländerbehörde in Deutschland einholen (§ 41 Abs. 1 Aufenthaltsverordnung).
>
> Bei Praktika mit einer Dauer von bis zu drei Monaten können Staatsangehörige bestimmter Länder ebenfalls visumsfrei einreisen (§17 Aufenthaltsverordnung in Verbindung mit §16 Beschäftigungsverordnung). Auf der Internetseite des Auswärtigen Amtes [Overview of visa requirements/exemptions for entry into the Federal Republic of Germany - Federal Foreign Office](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/-/231148) finden Sie eine aktuelle Staatenliste zur Visumpflicht, der Sie entnehmen können, ob Ihre Praktikantin/Ihr Praktikant unter diese spezielle Regelung fällt.
>
> Alle anderen Staatsangehörige sind grundsätzlich visumspflichtig.

Basically, it states that if you are entitled to a visa-free short stay and your internship is shorter than three months. That's the meaning of the second paragraph. Now, the last sentence could suggest that nationals from so-called annex I countries (countries whose citizens need a visa to enter the Schengen area) do need a visa for an internship but a careful reading reveals that's not the case. What it says is that nationals from other countries “generally” require a visa (i.e. if they are not entitled to a short stay through another means, like a residence permit in another EU country country).

Other sources suggest the permission you should apply for is a *residence* permit from the local *Ausländerbehörde* (and not from the *Bundesagentur für Arbeit*). I would recommend contacting both as soon as possible to inquire about the procedure.

Note that this only applies up to 90 days. If your stay in Germany lasts even 91 days, you do in principle require a visa or residence permit and you would need to apply for that before leaving Estonia.

[If you want to track the references in the text, do note that the structure of the Beschäftigungsverordnung changed in between. The contents of §16 are now covered by §30 Nummer 2 und 3, which in turns refer to §15.]

Comment: (-1) The first paragraph states: *Nationals of ... can enter the federal territory without a visa and **can obtain the required residence permit** for the internship at the local immigration office in Germany (Section 41 (1) Residence Ordinance)*. The application for an employment permit is **part of the residence permit process**. Since an **internship** is considered to be a gainful employment, a residence permit for Germany is needed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The first paragraph is about internships longer than three months. That list (“Australia, Israel, etc.”) is familiar and specific to Germany, entirely disconnected from Schengen rules (as it should since it is about a *long stay*). The interesting bit is the second paragraph. What do you make of that?

Comment: No, the first paragraph is about persons who don't need a visa and they must aquire the required residence permit for the internship (it states nothing about time in that paragraph). The second is similar (i.e. for Canadians). They must apply at their consulate of residence. Here I have experience from a Canadian friend who went through this process.

Comment: @MarkJohnson It's true that the first paragraph doesn't explicitly mention time but it refers to § 41 Abs. 1 Aufenthaltsverordnung, which reads “*Staatsangehörige von Australien […] können auch für einen Aufenthalt, **der kein Kurzaufenthalt ist,** visumfrei in das Bundesgebiet einreisen*” That's a very generic rule that applies to all residence permits (there is no mention of gainful employment in § 41 Abs. 1 Aufenthaltsverordnung) and it wouldn't make sense for these people to apply for a residence permit for a short stay. That's the process your Canadian friend went through.

Comment: Meanwhile, the second paragraph explains that *an even broader list of people* do not require a visa for an internship under 3 months. It's not limited to Canadian citizens (which are dealt with in the first paragraph) but covers all annex II nationals. Where do you think the difference between the first and second paragraph lies? Why do you think the second paragraph mentions the duration of the internship?

Comment: Thanks for the correction,Canada is indeed now on that list. At the time they weren't. This process (residence permit and where needed work permit as one step) has been in place for decades. The second paragraph of the university text states: **of up to three months** (von bis zu drei Monaten). The difference between the 2 paragraphs is that citizens of the first can **also** apply in Germany, the second will be issued a D-Visa at a consulate. Most likly for this short time without a conversion to a residence permit (i.e. no extra visit to the Immigration office).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Well, let's look at the first sentence. “*Bei Praktika mit einer Dauer von bis zu drei Monaten können Staatsangehörige bestimmter Länder **ebenfalls visumsfrei** einreisen*” Clearly, the second paragraph isn't about applying for a long-stay visa at a consulate, it explicitely states that the people in question can enter *without a visa*. So I am back to my original questions: Where do you think the difference between the first and second paragraph lies? Why do you think the second paragraph mentions the duration of the internship?

Comment: The wording in this **unofficial** source is clear in the first paragraph (an residence permit can/must be applied for). The second paragraph references **§ 17 (1) (AufenthV)** which states that persons who may enter visa free (based on *Article 4 Paragraph 1 of Regulation (EU) 2018/1806*) still require a residence permit when they are not *Business travelers* [§16 Business travelers BeschV](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beschv_2013/__16.html) (which is the case here). This is a **very** badly (unclearly) formulated paragraph.

Comment: Sorry portion missing: 'when **they are gainfully employed**, but are not...'.

Comment: This should be something in the form of:  A residence permit (§ 19c AufenthG) is required for all persons. Certain citizens [list of countries] may apply for this directly inside Germany.

Comment: That's not what the document says, I see that's finally sinking in. That you don't like it doesn't mean it's unclear. We can continue to discuss residence permits in a minute but do you realize now that it states unambiguously that a visa is not required? Will you correct your answer?

Comment: @MarkJohnson So we have finally reach the point where you realize your mistake and abandon the discussion? Let's just add this one to the growing list of questions with a demonstrably false answer of yours that you are not willing to edit even a little bit.

Comment: That is a false assumption on your part. **§ 17 (1) (AufenthV)** is very clear, just as the text at [Residence permit to start an internship - Services - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/305303/en/) is. These are official sources as apposed to your quoted text.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The text I quote is not the actual statute but it is just as official as berlin.de or most of what you are quoting and I note you had no problem with it until I explained what it actually means. In any case, § 17 (1) (AufenthV)  is about getting a *residence permit*, I said I was prepared to discuss that in a minute but only once you correct the first mistake: None of these sources mention a requirement to get a *visa*. Your answer still states this with no evidence whatsoever. It is demonstrably false in that respect.

Comment: The point you quote is #9. Please add point #7. Then the situation will become clearer. Also note that your quoted document is almost 10 years old (2011-01), so the list of those countries not needing a work permit/visa is no longer compleate.

Comment: Reading point 7 of the 2011 document and comparing wirhe the present day page of the Immigration office in Berlin seems to imply that the **procedure has changed**. 2011 first get the work permit, then apply for the visa. 2020 apply for visa, where the work permit will also be dealt with. That is the difference here.

Comment: Note also that the OP is **not** an employee being sent by his employer (where exceptions to this rule exists).

Comment: @MarkJohnson The situation is perfectly clear and you're just trying to dodge the issue by confusing many things, possibly because you insist on sticking to improper or imprecise terminology. What you need to start an internship is to secure permission to work. That's what EU sources call a “work permit” and that needs to happen before applying for a visa (if you need one) or residence title or permit. That hasn't changed and there is absolutely no contradiction between the various sources on that.

Comment: On the other hand, none of the sources you brought forward (very much including § 17 (1) AufenthV, no matter how you interpret it, and berlin.de) say anything about a purported need to apply for a visa. Those sources deal with residence permits and describe what you need to do once you entered Germany.

Comment: [Beschäftigung - ausländische Arbeitnehmer - Berlin.de](https://www.berlin.de/einwanderung/aufenthalt/erwerbstaetigkeit/artikel.874035.php) Translated: 'The work permit is **always issued** by the immigration office (in Berlin: the State Office for Immigration) together with the residence permit.  **A separate “work permit”, as it was previously issued by the employment office, has not existed since 01.01.2005**.' So even your 2011 source was outdated.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's useful information, as I said we can discuss that, for now I will add something about it in my answer. Meanwhile yours still contain much more serious mistakes, including repeated baseless claims that a *visa* is required even though all your objections to mine are based on multiple sources claiming it's required to apply for a residence permit (which would obviously be useless for someone with a long-stay visa and no intent to stay longer than 90 days). Are you going to ever correct that or are you still planning to dodge that question?

Comment: I am not 'dogging' the question at all. Visa free entry, for a short term stay, is only for **specific** purposes (mainly visiting). For other purposes, classified as **gainfully employed**, the visa free entry **for short stays** (Kurzaufenthalts) does not apply (§17 AufenthV). The *purpose* is what counts, not how long, in determining if a D-Visa (National Visa) is required or not. In cases where no extension is planed (for stays up to a year), a residence permit probably won't be issued since the D-Visa serves the same purpose.

Comment: A parallel sample: US ESTA (Visitor B Visa) [Travel Purposes Not Permitted on Visa Waiver Program](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html) – Examples: **study, for credit ; employment...**. Here too, the *purpose* is what counts, not the *duration*.

Comment: @MarkJohnson “Visa free entry, for a short term stay, is only for specific purposes (mainly visiting).” That's simply not true. We are not talking about the US visa waiver programme here (how is that even relevant?), you cannot just assume it is and refuse to consider the actual text of the law. EU law is very clear, the Schengen regime is based on duration, not purpose. I already quoted many things that document this in detail (the visa code, the *Handbook*).

Comment: It's not a coincidence that it's called a “long-stay visa” (not a "D visa”, let alone a “D-Visa“ as phoog explained to you elsewhere). Germany made a whole mess of this Schengen regime but you cannot just invent stuff like an obligation to get a long-stay visa or the notion a residence permit wouldn't be issued out of thin air. Do you have any evidence at all for that beyond your own circular refusal to consider it could be any other way?

Comment: Meanwhile, you yourself have quoted a berlin.de page regarding *residence permits*. If that's not relevant (since a residence permit wouldn't be issued), why are you even mentioning it? That's the question you have been dodging.

Comment: Yes, it is clear: [Article 6(3) of Regulation (EU)
 2018/1806](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32018R1806#d1e591-39-1): 'A Member State may provide for exceptions from the exemption from the visa requirement provided for in Article 4 **as regards persons carrying out a paid activity during their stay**.' And this is exactly what **§17 AufenthV** does. So your claim that it is illegal is false.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Not really, this does not call into question the basic distinction between short-stay and long-stay visas. Again, there is nothing in there that says Schengen visas are limited to some purposes, look at the Visa code and at the *Handbook*. This regulation only determines whether the visa exemption applies. If the exemption from article 4 is set aside, then the person is back to the regular regime that applies to nationals from annex I countries (i.e. a Schengen visa is required), which we discussed many times.

Comment: Although, reading careful §17 AufenthV doesn't say you have to apply for a long-stay visa, just some *Aufenthaltstitel*, which could be a Schengen short-stay visa. I (foolishly) trusted your interpretation on that point but it's possible the German implementation is in fact perfectly legal. What would definitely not be is the notion that you could set aside the entire Schengen regime based on purpose, that's still completely baseless.

Comment: But I see you tricked me into discussing the general case, which I was seeking to avoid as it allows you to dodge the question at hand. You still have presented no reason to doubt the information from the *Bundesagentur für Arbeit* regarding visas, all you have presented are pages about residence permits and regular long-term employment.

Comment: For a short internship, §17 Nummer 2 AufenthV would seem to apply. § 30 Nummer 2 BeschV refers to § 15 BeschV which would cover most internships like the OP's. I'll admit the reasoning is not simple, which I why I was always careful in my answer and I prefer to trust official sources like the *Bundesagentur für Arbeit*. What I do know is that there is no limitation of purpose in the Schengen regime and no general obligation to get a long-stay visa for short-term work. You really need to abandon this notion and quit using the phrase “D-Visa”, it's getting in the way of a productive discussion.

Comment: You do know that the Visa sticker (uniform format for visas) does use the 'short/long' terminology, only type (A, C, D) as defined in  ANNEX VII. This is how the border guards (and I assume Airlines) distinguish what the traveler has.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I obviously know that, so what? It's still called a long-stay visa throughout EU and German law… "D" is short-hand for long-stay. Are you seriously hiding behind this to try to rescue the fiction that the distinction is based on purpose when said annex VII *explicitely* defines the code as "D: long-stay visa”?

Comment: The danger on relying on PDF's, is that they often become outdated. The Bundesagentur für Arbeit has never issued residence permits (nor since 2005 work permits). That is done by the immigration office, so their site should be used as a reference since it is kept up to date. The indended benifit (I assume) is that the applicant only has to deal with one authority (in most cases the consulate).

Comment: @MarkJohnson A PDF is not ideal but it's way better than fanciful theories and impressionistic thinking. For example, you are again jumping seamlessly from “immigration office” to “consulate” with zero sources (in PDF or otherwise) to back that up. That's not how the law works. I will add some references to the current law on this and we can discuss it but first will you explain your contention that a “D-visa” would be a visa for a certain purpose? Annex VII, *which you invoked yourself* **defines it as a long-stay visa**, what do you not understand about that?

Comment: A D-Visa (this terminology is also used in the visahandbuch, which is the consulate instruction manual) is a national visa based on national laws (permission to work or take up residence etc.), with special conditions only valid for the issuing state. In other Schengen states it will be treated as C-Visa.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Sure but, again, it is a *long-stay* visa (and that phrase is much more appropriate, it's the one used in the law itself). I ask once more, what's unclear about that?

Comment: Because some of them are issued for a short period also, so it is misleading. Students often get one for 1 month if it issued shortly before the semester starts.

Comment: @MarkJohnson It's not misleading, it's simply the law. It's true a long-stay visa can be issued for less than three months in very limited cases (typically if you have exhausted your rights to short stays in the Schengen area). As I said many times, I am not ruling out the possibility that some countries improperly use them for other purposes but that's not a reason to invent a whole distinction between visas for different purposes out of thin air. That's clearly much more misleading.

Comment: Practical Handbook for Border Guards Definitions: 32. 'Long-stay visa' means **a national visa** issued by one of the Schengen States fully applying the Schengen acquis for stays exceeding three months *in accordance with Regulation (EU) No 265/2010* **or** in accordance with other Union law **or** its national law.

Comment: So, you opinion that a D-Visa that is issued according to it's national laws violents the quoted directive is not correct.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117513/discussion-on-answer-by-relaxed-internship-in-germany-as-a-non-eu-citizen-do-i).

Answer (score -4):

Yes.

These rules are for 3rd country nationals appling for a visa/residence permit in a Schengen Member state.

You must make the application in the country of your residence whether it is

- in your home country **or**
- in another Schengen member state

makes no difference.

> I have tried to research this everywhere but every single source about non-EU citizens working/interning in Germany is all about people that are coming from a country outside the EU.

This information is for persons who are **citizens** of a country outside the EU (not for persons that are coming from a country outside the EU).

---

> [§ 17 - Failure of the exemption for gainful employment during a short stay -AufenthV](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__17.html)
> (1) The requirement for entry and short stay is the person in accordance with Article 4 Paragraph 1 of Regulation (EU) 2018/1806 as amended and **the holder of a residence permit** or a national long-stay visa issued by a Schengen state **is not exempt from a residence permit requirement if they are gainfully employed** in the federal territory.

An **internship** is considered to be a gainful employment.

For 3rd country citizens, who are eligible to apply for a residence permit directly inside Germany, the [application for an employment permit](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/305303/en/) is part if that process.

For those who are **not** eligible to apply for a residence permit directly inside Germany, must do so in their country of residence.

Having a residence permit from another Schengen state does not effect this general rule.

---

**Sources**

- [Residence permit to start an internship - Services - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/305303/en/)

  - [§ 19c AufenthG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0518)
- [Overview of visa requirements/exemptions for entry into the Federal Republic of Germany - Federal Foreign Office](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/-/231148)
- [§ 17 - Failure of the exemption for gainful employment during a short stay -AufenthV](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__17.html)

Comment: You entirely failed to address the issue at hand (what to do for stays under 90 days) or, apparently, to comprehend the distinction between a visa and a work permit or the underlying logic of the Schengen system.

Comment: In your defense, https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__17.html does suggest Germany is violating EU law in this regard. As explained in my answer it still doesn't apply to internships, though.

Comment: @Relaxed A residence permit (and possible work conditions) are only valid for the country of issue. One country **cannot** grant permission to work in another country. The residence permit allows **visits** to other Schengen countries. So the question has been answered: the needed "internship visa" must be applied for. Exceptions exist only in areas where an employer has offices in both countries and allows, as an employee, for an short internship possible.

Comment: @Relaxed Last year, when the matter of British citizens receiving an unrestricted work permit was announced, there was a discussion about the fact that for those who often worked in multiple countries would no longer be able to do so. So your notion that work permits are covered in the Schengen code is not correct. If it was, there would have been an ECJ ruling by now.

Comment: We already went over this, that's still more of the same confusion. I agree that a Schengen country cannot grant permission to work in another country. That's why you need to secure that permission (in that case from the ZAV) *but not a visa* (as the person already has a right to *stay* in Germany). Those two things are distinct, that's the whole point! In fact, multiple German sources make it abundantly clear that you need to secure that permission *before* you can even apply for a visa in case you need one. That's completely clear and doesn't require an ECJ ruling (what for?)

Comment: Ditto for British citizens: the main issue in this scenario is staying for longer than 90 days across multiple countries (which they are allowed to do as EU citizens but not as third-country citizens), not the work permit issue. Leaving aside annex II nationals, let's consider annex I nationals for a minute, have you read the document from the BA cited in my answer? It directly contradicts the notion that someone who stays under Schengen short-stay rules (in that case visa-free) couldn't work lest they get a national long-stay visa. How do you account for that?

Comment: @Relaxed `you read the document from the BA cited in my answer?` Yes, it states that a residence permit is required. It also lists the citizenships that may apply for this in Germany. It **does not state** that holder of residence permits of other Schengen countries may do so also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117292/discussion-between-relaxed-and-mark-johnson).

Comment: Reminded of this question by https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/21576/internship-in-germany-as-a-non-eu-citizen-do-i-need-zav-pre-approval-letter-for, I note that we will add it to the long list of inaccurate answer you won't fix in spite of all the glaring mistakes that have been identified.