# Internship in Germany as a non-EU citizen, do I need ZAV pre-approval letter for a 3-month internship if I already have an Italian residence permit?

Tags: germany, working-visas, internship

I am a non-EU masters student in Italy and I recently completed the recruitment stages for an internship in Germany. Due to the uncertainty (covid-related) around my ability to obtain an internship visa and relocate to Germany, the company has not made an official yet. We are trying to figure out the best and easiest way for this transition since the German embassy in Rome is not granting visa appointments at the moment.

I recently read about the fact that I can take up a 3-months internship in Germany without an internship Visa provided I already have a type C (Schengen) Visa. The German embassy in Rome confirmed by email that I can go directly to Germany for the internship without a visa provided I have an Italian residence permit and a ZAV permission letter.

However, according to the Ordinance on the employment of foreign nationals (Beschäftigungsverordnung - BeschV) section 15, it was stated that "A residence permit for an internship does not require approval" and section 30.2 states that " Employment stays without a residence permit" is permitted for "Activities according to Sections 15 that are carried out for up to 90 days within a period of twelve months".

My understanding (based on these laws) is that I am exempted from obtaining a ZAV approval for an internship and I do not need to obtain a residence permit for an internship-related stay less than 90 days.

Is this correct? If you're familiar with or recently dealt with the process, please what else am I missing that could help?

Comment: § 15 doesn't cover all internships, under which item does your fall?

Comment: Earlier questions on related topics: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20567/internship-in-germany-as-a-non-eu-citizen-do-i-need-the-internship-visa-if-i-am/21441#comment35162_21441, https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20545/internship-in-an-eu-country-with-a-french-visa-non-eu-citizen and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44265/am-i-allowed-to-do-a-six-week-internship-in-germany-on-a-normal-schengen-visa No duplicate though, those Q&A go over the rules you already know but no feedback from someone with direct recent experience of the process.

Comment: Thank you for the links. Mine falls under 15.6. The embassy clarified that I need the ZAV pre-approval because it's a voluntary internship after my fourth semester. Thanks.

Comment: You could answer your own question then?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and emailed Bundesagentur für Arbeit (BA). In my case, the officer said that, with the internship

- study-related, and
- less than 90 days within 12 months, and
- during my study after 4th semester in H+ institution

and thus

- under 15.6

there is no need for BA's 'Einvernehmen' because it is not considered an employment (BeschV § 30 Nr. 2; Nichtbeschäftigungsfiktion (16a.15.8) from [here](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/datei/dok_ba146473.pdf) and page 231 and page 410 [here](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/blob/207816/e025d7a51aa0e20f5567c6f7478c8fd6/visumhandbuch-data.pdf)). Therefore, you only need legitimate way of entry + stay for 90 days (e.g. with your EU residence permit/visa-free passport/...).

> Bei Kurzaufenthalten ist darüber hinaus § 30 BeschV zu beachten. In diesen Fällen liegt keine Beschäftigung i.S.d. AufenthG („Nichtbeschäftigungsfiktion“) und somit keine Erwerbstätigkeit vor, die einer gesonderten Erlaubnis bedarf.

> Die Ausübung von Tätigkeiten, die gem. § 30 BeschV nicht als Beschäftigungen im Sinne des Aufenthaltsgesetzes gelten, **ist daher auch mit einem Schengen-Visum mit der Anmerkung "Erwerbstätigkeit nicht erlaubt" zulässig.**

and

> Für studienfachbezogene Praktika kann während des Studiums an einer ausländischen Hochschule nach dem vierten Fach-Semester ein Aufenthaltstitel nach § 16a AufenthG i.V.m. § 15 Nr. 6 BeschV im Einvernehmen mit der BA erteilt werden.

> Praktika nach § 15 Nr. 6 BeschV, die maximal 90 Tage innerhalb eines Zeitraums von 12 Monaten ausgeübt werden sollen, gelten nach § 30 Nr. 2 BeschV nicht als Beschäftigung. **Positivstaater benötigen dann weder das Einvernehmen der BA, noch einen Aufenthaltstitel. Visumpflichtige Staatsangehörige benötigen zwar ein Visum, aber kein Einvernehmen der BA.**

and

> Non-EU citizens living in one of the countries that do apply the agreement fully (so-called Schengen States) with a valid residence permit **do not need a visa** for visits to Germany of up to 90 days in any period of 180 days **when not taking up work.**